# order by date in sqlite database example in android 2.0.3

Tags: android, sqlite

In android 2.0.3 i want a suggestion how to make my cursor data in descending order.i know in sqlite dates are stored in text but i retrieved the cursor and parse the date but than im not able to sort them in descending order..needed help..
this is my code if some can help

int cnt=rs_inc.getCount();

```
                String d[]=null;
                SimpleDateFormat formatter ; 
             Date date1 = null,date2 = null ; 
              formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");
             boolean swap = true;
                    while(swap)
                    {
                        swap = false;           
                        for(int i =1; i < cnt; i++) 
                        {
                        d[i]=rs_inc.getString(2);
                         try {
                                date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(rs_inc.getString(2));
                                }catch(Exception e){}
                                rs_inc.moveToNext();
                                if(rs_inc.isAfterLast()){
                                    rs_inc.moveToPrevious();
                                }

                                d[i+1]=rs_inc.getString(2);
                         try {
                                date2 = (Date)formatter.parse(rs_inc.getString(2));
                                }catch(Exception e){}
                            if(date1.before(date2))     
                            {
                                swap = true;    
                                String temp = d[i];     
                                d[i] = d[i + 1];    
                                d[i + 1] = temp;        
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: in Sqlite, dates might be stored as string but you can define column type as `DATETIME` and let sqlite do the ordering work

Comment: yes from the syntax i'have written the data type as DATETIME but its still not working and taking that as string only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are using wrong date format.

In order to sort by `DATETIME` in SQLite, you need to use correct date format as below:

```
DateFormat dateFormatISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i am new to android so can you pls explain in detail??this is my create table syntax..db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_INCOME+ "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,incomename TEXT ,price INTEGER,date DATETIME)");

Comment: instead of using `date DATE`, try using `[date] DATETIME`

Comment: How can I sort date in descending order?

Comment: Your query may look like this `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY myDate DESC`. So the key thing is **ORDER BY [column] DESC**